# IP on blacklist due to IP network listed

Tags: google-compute-engine, blacklist

My google compute engine's/vps IP (146.148.22.101) is blacklisted on the https://www.uceprotect.net/ list as LEVEL 2. Meaning the network 146.148.0.0/17 is listed not my IP itself - Mine is green. I know it is probably google's job to fix this but I do not know how or where to report this. Microsoft mail servers are rejecting all incoming mail originating from my ip because of this listing.

uceprotect.net suggests to register on whitelisted.org costing 25euros/month. Not going to happen.

Can someone help or guide me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

[Blacklist screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5zFX.png)

Comment: Why don't you just replace that IP with a different one ? You will have to restart the VM

Comment: I think this will indeed be the quickest option... thank you for the reply.

Comment: You mention that Microsoft is refusing your emails. You cannot send emails from Google Cloud VMs except through a relay host (Office 365, Gmail, etc). Can you provide details on how you are sending emails? You might be chasing a problem that will repeat with a new IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just replace that IP with a different one ? You will have to restart the VM

Comment: This should be more like a comment than an answer.